# Learning Rigid Body Constraints (Slider & Piston) - Active object keeps passing through passive?

Tags: physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

So I'm trying to teach myself some basic rigid body physics with rigid body constraints. I have a 2.83.4 .blend file with several collections (one for each constraint I'm trying to understand) and I'm struggling with the Slider and Piston constraints. Basically, I make two cubes and connect them and assign the constraints accordingly. When I try to simulate it, it does work initially, but the active cube that is constrained just passes through the passive cube, thus ruining the simulation. However, when I make a new passive cube and put it next to the original passive cube (the one that got constrained to the active cube) the active cube doesn't pass through it. I haven't had any issue with the Fixed, Hinge, or Point constraints, just these two so far.

All my googling has found videos from much older version of Blender, or a recommendation to increase the number of steps. I've tried everything I've seen, but I can't figure this one out. Can someone take a look at my file?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the objects 'Active1' and 'Passive (connected to Active1)' to collide. These two objects share a rigid body constraint through the empty 'Piston Constraint.' This constraint has 'Disable Collisions' checked. This is telling Bullet to ignore 'Active1' and 'Passive (connected to Active1)' collisions.

Comment: Oh my goodness... how did I miss this... Thank you very much! A valuable lesson has been learned tonight... Thanks again! :)